# Reversing Implicit Differentiation to determine One Parameter Family of Lines

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the orthogonal trajectories of the one parameter family of lines y-Cx = 0;

Answer is x^2 + y^2 = C

Of course you can always do implicit differentiation on each answer from the set of choices. But given there is no answer; how can you determine the orthogonal trajectory? Any Hint? What technique should I try to study?

Comment: I'm not getting that what is your exact problem? Your answer for the $y-cx=0$ is correct . If, you are unable to find this answer tell me i will post the solution, otherwise be more clear with your problem

Comment: I think the question is this: if you're given a family like the line-family above, and a multiple-choice set of possible orthogonal trajectories, you can determine which one is the right one, through implicit differentiation. But if you've just got the one-parameter family of curves, how can you determine the family of orthogonal trajectories? (Presumably, by writing down a differential equation that says that $[-y'(t), x'(t)]\cdot F(x(t), y(t)) = 0$, where $F(u, v)$ is the tangent vector to the one-parameter family at the point $(u, v)$ ... and then solving the DE.]

Comment: @Chiranjeev Yes, I am unable to find the solution that leads to said answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, First of all differentiate the given family of curves with respect to independent variable Here, I am assuming that $x$ as independent variable then derivative of given curve is $$y'=c$$. Now, using this value of $c$ in given equation of curve we have, $$y-xy'=0$$. Now for the orthogonal trajectory replace $y'$ by $\frac{-1}{y'}$, Then you will get, $$yy'+x=0$$, i.e.

$$ydy+xdx=0$$. On integration we get that, $$x^2+y^2=2c$$ replace $2c$ by new constant $C$

we get the Answer,  $$x^2+y^2=C$$